# How to disable background content scrolling in position fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

How to disable content scrolling behind fixed position ?

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/k6sk4a0L/4/**

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4c68f9;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default.affix {
  background-color: #4762ed;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-default.affix + .container {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.navbar-default .nav-property,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a:after,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a:hover:after {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:after,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus:after {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(76, 104, 249, 0.95);
  border: none;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /*&.collapsing{
   height: 0 !important;
   opacity: 0;
  }*/
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam minus est aliquid tempore hic placeat eligendi corrupti! Aspernatur sint fuga minima, assumenda quo, obcaecati recusandae dolores sequi, eum culpa dicta!</h3>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus laborum dignissimos blanditiis nostrum at quibusdam neque eum iusto, excepturi cupiditate voluptatibus ipsum, distinctio dolores, quis deleniti architecto libero iure suscipit.</h2>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim laboriosam repellendus, tempore fugiat, eveniet dolorem quas error. Enim officiis, recusandae, dolorum sed ad fugit voluptas atque adipisci aut tempora, reprehenderit.</h1>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo omnis corporis, minima modi quasi est facilis quo vel vitae labore provident, impedit nostrum excepturi molestiae velit repellendus libero rerum numquam.</h3>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati ab, explicabo in enim eveniet, qui voluptatem, fugit culpa optio fugiat veniam eos delectus harum! Sequi similique quos a minus expedita.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use jquery solution for this.?

Comment: @Himesh Aadeshara There should be **CSS** solution the issue, however I am happy to fix with jQuery as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi i know what i have given is the one kind of hack we can say to crack our problem

**NOTE : there is might problem with navigation class manipulation first time page loads so please look around it**

here is my hack for your problem using jquery

**because when you have opened you navigation you might not probably work with your back-end body content**  keeping this thing in my mind i have applied this approach please look out in fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('hiddenApply');
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click',function(){
       debugger;
       if($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "false"){
           $('body').addClass('hiddenApply');
       }else{
        $('body').removeClass('hiddenApply');
       }
    });    
})
```

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4c68f9;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default.affix {
  background-color: #4762ed;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-default.affix + .container {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.navbar-default .nav-property, .navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a:after,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a:hover:after {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:after, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus:after {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0) translateY(-4px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-1px) translateY(3px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(76, 104, 249, 0.95);
  border: none;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /*&.collapsing{
   height: 0 !important;
   opacity: 0;
  }*/
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
  bottom: 0;
}
.hiddenApply{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam minus est aliquid tempore hic placeat eligendi corrupti! Aspernatur sint fuga minima, assumenda quo, obcaecati recusandae dolores sequi, eum culpa dicta!</h3>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus laborum dignissimos blanditiis nostrum at quibusdam neque eum iusto, excepturi cupiditate voluptatibus ipsum, distinctio dolores, quis deleniti architecto libero iure suscipit.</h2>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim laboriosam repellendus, tempore fugiat, eveniet dolorem quas error. Enim officiis, recusandae, dolorum sed ad fugit voluptas atque adipisci aut tempora, reprehenderit.</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo omnis corporis, minima modi quasi est facilis quo vel vitae labore provident, impedit nostrum excepturi molestiae velit repellendus libero rerum numquam.</h3>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati ab, explicabo in enim eveniet, qui voluptatem, fugit culpa optio fugiat veniam eos delectus harum! Sequi similique quos a minus expedita.</h2>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle you can check out though there is some problem i want to give the approach.

[Check out](http://jsfiddle.net/k6sk4a0L/15/)

Comment: @Muhammed Athimannil hi please checkout i know it's a hack but i can't found any thing that is going wrong so

Comment: the solutions seems to me fine but unfortunately the class  `. hiddenApply` doesn't add to `body` for the first click on `.navbar-toggle`

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Change click function like this `$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(event) { $("body").toggleClass("hidden-apply"); });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't wish to overlap your bottom body content with your navigation-bar text (which is fixed) when page scrolls, if that's the case then add class 'navbar-fixed-top' to your nav tag like below -

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

add some padding in body to make content start in beginning from the below of navbar -

```
body { padding-top: 60px; }
```

Comment: the reason why not using `.navbar-fixed-top` is I am using **affix.js** while scroll started.

Comment: Can you provide more details on why using affix.js, and then why can't use `.navbar-fixed-top`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove style `bottom: 100%;` in your CSS class `.navbar-default .navbar-collapse`.

If you want set height of navbar, remove the style `height: 100%;` because it was overridden by Bootstrap. Use `height: 60px !important` instead.